# Java: How to specify JVM argument -XX:ErrorFile and preserve automatic PID in filename

Tags: java, jvm-arguments, hs-err

I am using the JNI and when there is a crash due to errors in the target application a hs_err_pid*.log file is generated. I want to change the default location where that file is stored.
Now, from searching around I understand this can be achieved using the JVM argument -XX:ErrorFile.

The [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#DebuggingOptions) says that the default for this parameter is ./hs_err_pid`<`pid`>`.log

Now, when I override the default, how can I tell the JVM to still include the process id in the filename? 
I have obviously tried to literally put targetDir/hs_err_pid`<`pid`>`.log as a command line parameter, but this led to the whole argument being ignored (and the file being stored to the default location, i.e. the working directory).
If I only say targetDir/hs_err_pid.log the file is stored where I want it, but does not get a process id appended to the filename.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
-XX:ErrorFile=targetDir/hs_err_pid_%p.log
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. This looks like exactly what I was looking for. Will test tomorrow at work and post back results.

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm!

Comment: How can I test / simulate this? I mean, how can I cause the JVM to crash and write something in this error file?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows:

```
-XX:ErrorFile=C:\targetDir\hs_err_pid_%%p.log
```

Comment: Two percentage signs?